# OnActivityResult always returns RESULT CANCELED (Code: 0) on Android 11

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-11, android-storage

Sadly, Android 11 storage restrictions are too hard and confusing.

I'm trying to pick a document using the below code

```
    fun onFile(activity: AppCompatActivity?, fragmentContext: Fragment?, isMultiple: Boolean?, pFileMimeTypes: Array<String>?): Intent {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
                action = Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, isMultiple ?: false)
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
            }
    
            val fileMimeTypes = pFileMimeTypes ?: FileUtil.mimeTypes
            intent.type = if (fileMimeTypes.size == 1) fileMimeTypes[0] else "*/*"
            if (!fileMimeTypes.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, fileMimeTypes)
            }
    
    
            val list = activity?.packageManager?.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL)
            if (list?.size!! > 0) {
                if (fragmentContext == null) {
                    activity.startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(
                                    intent,
                                    activity.getString(R.string.m_selectFile_txt)
                            ), FILE_CODE
                    )
                } else {
                    fragmentContext.startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(
                                    intent,
                                    activity.getString(R.string.m_selectFile_txt)
                            ), FILE_CODE
                    )
                }
            }
// returning intent is not being used anywhere else
            return intent
        }
```

Although I have all files access permission `Environment.isExternalStorageManager()` but still after selecting document(PDF) from the external storage (download or any folder), `OnActvityResult` is being called with `result code 0`. I need the Uri of the selected document to proceed further.

For any other reference, below is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="*****Hidden*******">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"

        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:exported="true"
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.attachmentmanager"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider"
                tools:replace="android:resource" />
        </provider>
    </application>



    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
            <!-- If you don't know the MIME type in advance, set "mimeType" to "*/*". -->
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <!-- If you don't know the MIME type in advance, set "mimeType" to "*/*". -->
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>


</manifest>
```

I must be missing some point. Everything is working fine below **Android 11**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
` Removge those lines. You cannot grant anything.

Comment: `Although I have all files access permission` That permission has nothing to do and is not needed for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. You need no permission at all to use it.

Comment: I dont understand your `<queries>` in manifest. They are not needed. Maybe they harm...

Comment: @blackapps `<queries>` are for package visibility.

Comment: I have no idea why you call that action a package. But i repeat: they are not needed for using that action and you better try without. Maybe it causes your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

startActivityForResult is deprecated

Refer this [link](https://medium.com/@patelsneh18/startactvivityforresult-deprecated-alternative-and-using-it-outside-activity-class-bc9331cf896)

Use Activity Results API
[Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect this could be an issue on Android 11.

Comment: @Zaid Mirza, it is no issue here on Android 11 and 12.

Comment: @blackapps, After implementing Activity results API, everything working fine. Otherwise, I was getting RESULT CANCELLED in OnActvityResult when I select a document.

Comment: Deprecated for java maybe, but there's no indication its deprecated for c#.  In any event, there is nothing in the Android API documentation saying it's deprecated.

Comment: @ZaidMirza I am developing on Android sdk 21 to 33. For sdk> 30 however with the new api ActivityResult is always CANCELED.